# TypeError: state.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I try to use the `find()` method but I get

> cartItems.find is not a function

what happens? and how to fix it?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function cart() {
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])

    const add = (pro) => {
        const exist = cartItems.find((item) => {
            return item.id === pro.id;
        });
        if (exist) {
            setCartItems(
                cartItems.find((item) => {
                    return item.id === exist.id
                        ? {...exist, qnty: exist.qnty + 1}
                        : item;
                })
            );
        } else {
            setCartItems([...cartItems, {...pro, qnty: 1}]);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>cart</div>
    )
}

export default cart
```

Comment: The `find` method itself will return an individual item from an array, so the first if condition will ruin the `cartItems` value and make it a non-array element.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because `cartItems` is no longer an array.

According to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

In this part of your code -

```
setCartItems(
  cartItems.find((item) => {
    return item.id === exist.id
      ? {...exist, qnty: exist.qnty + 1}
      : item;
    })
);
```

You set `cartItems` to be the first element of your condition there with `find()`. So next render, `cartItems` is no longer an array, but a an item. Which have no `find`.

Comment: which you did inside `setCartItems` that can be done separately then use that obj to your `setCartItems`. So, your `cartItems` won't be mutated and the rest will be working.